# Is there a pre Api level 19 version of Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT?

Tags: android

To let the user feed a document to my app there are two `Intent` actions:

```
ACTION_GET_CONTENT (Api level 1)
ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT (Api level 19)
```

To let the user save a document I only found:

```
ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT (Api level 19)
```

Now I was wondering, is there a pre Api level 19 way of letting the user save a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry, there is no real equivalent to `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` for Android 4.3 and older. You will need to have your own UI to let the user choose a location on the filesystem to save your content.